# How to have custom matching logic for action types in a redux-toolkit slice reducer

Tags: redux-toolkit

I want to create a reducer that matches actions using runtime calculated value. The use case is that I'm managing a busy indicator automatically by reference counting actions that end in `/pending`, etc...

I'm wanting to use redux-toolkit on this new project and I realize I could create a vanilla redux reducer but I'd prefer to keep things consistent if possible. Is there a way to wire up a slice so that it uses a custom match for an action type matching in it's reducer?

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Mark, the creator of redux-toolkit it looks like this feature isn't supported as the goal of the toolkit is optimize the 80+ % use cases and custom action type matching logic is a rare use case.